# Floating Feedback Button on SharePoint 2010

Tags: client-object-model

I need to create a floating feedback button at the bottom of the master page. 
This should appear at the right side of the home page and all the pages. 
I should open a new modal form to give the feedback. After filling the form, I should be able to send the form data in email. Please let me know how do I achieve this.

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

- Add the necessary HTML, CSS and Javascript to the master page. An excellent example of such floating Feedback button can be found at: http://mediaformations.com/examples/SimpleFeedbackButton.html
- Create the feedback page on the root of your site collection (ex. Pages/Feedback.aspx) or better yet create it at 'layouts' folder if allowed.
- Create a webpart (to be added to the feedback page) or custom aspx page under layouts folder.
- On your master page, use SP Dialog (SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( options );) to open up the feedback page.

If you're on SP 2013, you could do this without any server side code, look up 'SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail' api

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an HTML tag in your masterpage, if you want to have the feedback button on each page of your site. Inside the `body` tag add a `<div id="feedback"><a href="#" title="ffeedback">Feedback</a></div>`. You may specify some link in the anchor tag or define an event for your form to be redirected somewhere (creating a category for this might be the ideal approach).

Also, with the help of css properties you can position it the way you want (something like what is mentioned below).

```
#feedback
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:80%;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I want to create the whole feedback form and send the email after filling that.